# how to add character " to a column in pandas -> df.update and other methods dont seem to work properly

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add quotation marks to the beginning and the end of a row in pandas like such:

Go from:

```
hello name tom hi
```

to:

```
"hello name tom hi"
```

I'm also trying to add the quotation marks to the column but its the same problem. 
The column names are the following: greeting1 name1 name2 greeting2

When I try to change the column name I do the following:

```
    df = df.rename(index=str, columns={'greeting1': '"greeting1', 'greeting2': 'greeting2"'})
```

it works fine when I do df.head() but outputs something like this when I do

```
tfile= open("test6.txt","w+")
df.to_csv(tfile,sep=";",index=False)
tfile.close()
```

output:

```
"""greeting1";name1;name2;"greeting2"""
```

Same for the values in the columns:

```
df.update('"' + df[['greeting1']].astype(str))
```

OR EVEN:

```
df['greeting1'] = '"' + df['greeting1'].astype(str)
df['greeting2'] = df['greeting2'].astype(str) + '"'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Run your `.rename` and `.update` statements as normal, then maybe try `import csv` and `df.to_csv(tfile,sep=";",index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)` ..?

Comment: works like a charm! I had tried different types of quoting but not QUOTE_NONE, thanks!